# Flink Application failure on savepoint

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am observing a failure whenever I trigger a savepoint on my Flink Application which otherwise runs without issues.

Job Details:

- Deployment: AWS Kinesis Data Analytics(Kubernetes)
- 5 Task Managers
- Backend: RocksDB
- Kinesis Data Units: 256 KPU

**Flink Graph(Parallelism indicated in brackets)**

[image: Flink Graph(Parallelism indicated in brackets)]

Task Manager Details screenshot

[image: Task Manager Details screenshot]

Exception Root Cause on Flink UI:

```
org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.exception.RemoteTransportException: Error at remote task manager '142.151.130.161/142.151.130.161:6121'.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.CreditBasedPartitionRequestClientHandler.decodeMsg(CreditBasedPartitionRequestClientHandler.java:294)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.CreditBasedPartitionRequestClientHandler.channelRead(CreditBasedPartitionRequestClientHandler.java:183)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.NettyMessageClientDecoderDelegate.channelRead(NettyMessageClientDecoderDelegate.java:115)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1475)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1224)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1271)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:505)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:444)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:283)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1421)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:930)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:794)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:424)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:326)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:918)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.partition.ProducerFailedException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.PartitionRequestQueue.writeAndFlushNextMessageIfPossible(PartitionRequestQueue.java:224)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.PartitionRequestQueue.enqueueAvailableReader(PartitionRequestQueue.java:108)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.PartitionRequestQueue.userEventTriggered(PartitionRequestQueue.java:173)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:327)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.userEventTriggered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:117)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.userEventTriggered(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:369)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:327)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.userEventTriggered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:117)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.userEventTriggered(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:369)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:327)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.userEventTriggered(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1439)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:327)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireUserEventTriggered(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:924)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.PartitionRequestQueue.lambda$notifyReaderNonEmpty$0(PartitionRequestQueue.java:87)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:416)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:331)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:798)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1354)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SubtaskCheckpointCoordinatorImpl.finishAndReportAsync(SubtaskCheckpointCoordinatorImpl.java:451)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SubtaskCheckpointCoordinatorImpl.checkpointState(SubtaskCheckpointCoordinatorImpl.java:267)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.lambda$performCheckpoint$5(StreamTask.java:917)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$1.runThrowing(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:47)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.performCheckpoint(StreamTask.java:907)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.triggerCheckpointOnBarrier(StreamTask.java:873)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.CheckpointBarrierHandler.notifyCheckpoint(CheckpointBarrierHandler.java:113)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.CheckpointBarrierAligner.processBarrier(CheckpointBarrierAligner.java:198)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.CheckpointedInputGate.pollNext(CheckpointedInputGate.java:93)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTaskNetworkInput.emitNext(StreamTaskNetworkInput.java:158)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamOneInputProcessor.processInput(StreamOneInputProcessor.java:67)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.processInput(StreamTask.java:346)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMailboxStep(MailboxProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMailboxLoop(MailboxProcessor.java:181)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runMailboxLoop(StreamTask.java:566)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:537)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:724)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:549)
    ... 1 more
```

Any help would be appreciated to debug the issue

Comment: How many slots do you have on each TM? Looks like thereis no enough slots for the parallelism that you want

Comment: Try to increase `taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots`